# covariance isn't positive definite

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, probability, variance

I'm trying to calculate sample covariance of a given data.

the code I wrote is:

```
def calcCov(x):
    m, n = x.shape

    mean = np.mean(x, axis=0)
    cov = np.zeros((n, n))
    for j in range(0, n):
        for k in range(0, n):
            sum = 0
            for i in range(0, m):
                sum += (x[i, j] - mean[j])*(x[i, k] - mean[k])
            cov[j, k] = sum / (m - 1.0)

    return cov
```

It is not the most efficient way to do this, but it is simple and is a direct copy of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_mean_and_covariance#Sample_covariance to the best of my knowledge.

Covariance matrix is always positive semidefinite. But when I calculate the eigenvalues (with np.eig) i see negative eigenvalues sometimes.

for example the code

```
data = np.random.rand(2, 2)
print data
cov = calcCov(data)
eigvals, eigvec = np.linalg.eig(cov)
print cov
print eigvals
```

prints the output

```
[[ 0.12873309  0.92079275]
 [ 0.90018866  0.73197021]]
[[ 0.29757185 -0.0728341 ]
 [-0.0728341   0.01782698]]
[  3.15398823e-01  -3.46944695e-18]
```

as a mathematician that is very unsettling. Why does this happen? simple numerical errors? did i make a mistake in my calculation of the covariance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I would suggest to use numpy's covariance function, since it will be more efficient: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html

Given the "negative" eigenvalues you have is e-18, it is fair to consider it 0 up to numerical error.